# replication between xampp localhost database and remote server database

Tags: php, database, server, xampp, localhost

I need to create replication between two different databases one is localhost database as the master and the second one is the remote server database as slave?

I have a codeigniter web application which is installed on both servers now I want to do that if the internet is not connected all application data should be saved in localhost database, when internet is connected all databases should be copied to the remote server database.

Is there any way I can attain this using localhost phpmyadmin or PHP scripts?

**LocalHost Master Setting**
[image]

**How Do I Create Remote Server As Slave**
[image]

Comment: Remote database would have to be setup as master and localhost as slave. It is slave that connects to master to fetch changes and to do that it needs an external IP of database host.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way would be to set up mysql replication. You could set up local mysql server as master and remote server as slave, so that all changes would automatically replicate from localhost to remote host. You also must be able to open mysql port on the remote server to listen to your local machine.

Here would be a basic tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

Comment: can you give me example pleasE?